# How to implement a password text input widget (input obscured) for google-apps-script gmail add-on?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons, google-apps-script-addon

Couldn't see any option available for the TextInput widget to obscure a user's input for fields like password, etc.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/text-input

Comment: Edit.. Nm sorry.

Comment: Check the [Serve HTML as a Google Docs, Sheets, or Forms user interface](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/#serve_html_as_a_google_docs_sheets_or_forms_user_interface) guide in creating your custom UI for your google app script apps by using [Custom Menus](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/menu).

Comment: I don't think HtmlService is available for Gmail add-ons... It keeps showing "markup" related error when that's used...

Comment: This is good workaround -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/49010224/3275211

Answer (score 1):

In the overview section of the CardService, 
It quotes:

“Currently you can only use this service to construct Gmail add-ons.“

So HtmlService is not available in constructing 
Gmail addon’s currently.  And there is no option 
In the CardService object to obscure the textInput 
widget.  The reference says when constructing
your addon to keep it simple, nothing complex.
You may want to rethink your use-case for your addon.