# Password field in Gmail add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I'm new to Apps Script.

I have created the login form using the card services in the Apps Script.

I have created the `text` field for getting the username from the user. Like that, I also want to create the `password` field to get the password from the user. For this, I didn't get the password field in the card service like the text field.

How can I make this field as a password field? Or how to create a new password field?

Example code to create text field:

```
var textuserName = CardService.newTextInput()
    .setFieldName("text_username")
    .setTitle("Username")
    .setHint("Please enter username");
   loginSection.addWidget(textuserName);
```

Comment: You aren't expected to provide a login and password card within the add-on. Please review the Gmail addon documentation regarding authorization of external services https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/how-tos/non-google-services https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/guides/restrictions#wzxhzdk9wzxhzdk10charge_users_to_install

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Password type field in gmail card service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47904710/password-type-field-in-gmail-card-service)